# How to construct delegate function in order to run different lines of code in each use case

Tags: c#, mongodb, logging, action, func

I'm new to delegates, Func<> and Action<>. I've tried reading several stack overflow post and documentation but to no avail.

The question is just as much aimed at getting an understanding of how i should conceptualize the problem, or if i should think in completely different terms. Anyhow here we go...

I have a BaseRepository class connected to a mongoDB. Below we see an example on one of the methods associated with this BaseClass

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll(int skip = 0, int limit = 100)
{
    return await DefaultCollection
        .Find(Filter.Empty)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Limit(limit)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

What i want to do is to implement some tracking which tracks communication time in elapsed millis between the API and the DB, in order for me to be better at prioritizing optimizations. So in simple terms the method should look like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll(int skip = 0, int limit = 100)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    var result = await DefaultCollection
        .Find(Filter.Empty)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Limit(limit)
        .ToListAsync();
    sw.Stop();

    Logger.PushContext("Elapsed Milles to DB", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    return result;

}
```

This would however be tidious to write into every single method so i was wondering what best practice could be and thought about making something like the following: WARNING PSEUDO CODE INCOMMING ;)

[image]

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll(int skip = 0, int limit = 100)
    {
        return await DefaultCollection
            .Find(Filter.Empty)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Limit(limit)
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// PSEUDO CODE. ONLY PSEUDO CODE
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected async Task<TResult> ExecuteCmd(* Inject code into this method* injectedCode)
    {

        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        var result = injectedCode.Run();

        sw.Stop();

        Logger.PushContext("Elapsed milli to db", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        return result;
    }
```

This way each request would be logged and the only change i should make was to put each method inside the ExecuteCmd.

Maybe something like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll(int skip = 0, int limit = 100)
{
    return await ExecuteCmd(c =>
    {
        DefaultCollection
            .Find(Filter.Empty)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Limit(limit)
            .ToListAsync();
    });
}
```

where this code is run inside the ExecuteCmd as "injectedCode.run".

I imagined that the ExecuteCmd, could take different kind of statements and respectively return different results...

Please let me know if this is way to ambigious. I'm sorry if it is, please let me know if i'm asking some more underlining question, so i can rephrase.

Best regards! Thanks in advance

The whole base repository is seen here for reference:

**Edit**
For anyones future reference this is the updated base-repository, hope it may help others!

```
public abstract class MongoReadmodelRepository<TEntity> : IMongoReadmodelRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    protected readonly ILogger Logger;
    protected readonly IMongoDatabase DefaultDatabase;
    protected readonly string CollectionName = $"rm-{typeof(TEntity).Name.ToLower()}";
    protected IMongoCollection<TEntity> DefaultCollection =>
        DefaultDatabase.GetCollection<TEntity>(CollectionName);


    protected UpdateDefinitionBuilder<TEntity> Update => Builders<TEntity>.Update;
    protected SortDefinitionBuilder<TEntity> Sort => Builders<TEntity>.Sort;
    protected FilterDefinitionBuilder<TEntity> Filter => Builders<TEntity>.Filter;
    protected ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<TEntity> Projection => Builders<TEntity>.Projection;

    public MongoReadmodelRepository(IMongoClient client, IOptions<ProjectionsPersistenceConfiguration> config, ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        DefaultDatabase = client.GetDatabase(config.Value.DefaultProjectionsDatabaseName);

        if (!CollectionExists(DefaultDatabase, CollectionName))
            DefaultDatabase.CreateCollection(CollectionName);
    }


    public async Task<bool> Delete(Guid id)
    {
        Logger.Information("Trying to delete {Entity} with {Id}", typeof(TEntity).Name, id);
        return (await DefaultCollection.DeleteOneAsync(Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id)))
            .IsAcknowledged;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll(int skip = 0, int limit = 100)
    {
        return await ExecuteCmd(
            () =>
                DefaultCollection
                    .Find(Filter.Empty)
                    .Skip(skip)
                    .Limit(limit)
                    .ToListAsync()
        );
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetByIndex(int index, int collectionSize)
    {
        return await DefaultCollection.Find(Filter.Empty)
            .Skip(index)
            .Limit(1)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetPaged(int page, int pageSize)
    {
        return await GetAll(page * pageSize, pageSize);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetById(Guid id)
    {
        return await DefaultCollection.Find(b => b.Id == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Guid> Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        await DefaultCollection.InsertOneAsync(entity, new InsertOneOptions());

        Logger.Information("Saved {@Entity}", entity);
        return entity.Id;
    }

    private bool CollectionExists(IMongoDatabase db, string collectionName)
    {
        var filter = new BsonDocument("name", collectionName);
        var collections = db.ListCollections(new ListCollectionsOptions { Filter = filter });
        return collections.Any();
    }

    protected async Task<TResult> ExecuteCmd<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> query)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        //Start stopwatch
        sw.Start();

        var result = await query();

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Logging execution time between API and mongoDB: Execution time in millis = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include all code as text in your question. Screenshots make it impossible to simply copy/paste into tests and answers. The arrows are useful for visualizing the idea but the screenshot must only be supplemental.

Comment: @madreflection i've added the entire baserepository, is this sufficient?

Comment: Too much. Looking for just the code that was in the screenshot.

Comment: That is, the part that wasn't already included as text.

Comment: @madreflection the code snippet above the image should illustrate half of the picture, the 2nd method is just some pseudo code. Anyhow, should be visible under the picture :) Please write if there is anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly simple translation.  You want a method that takes no arguments (as demonstrated by `injectedCode.Run()`, is awaitable and so must return an awaitable object like `Task<T>` , and has a result of type `TResult`.  Thus, your delegate parameter should be of type `Func<Task<TResult>>`.

```
protected async Task<TResult> ExecuteCmd<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> query)
{
    // ...
    var result = await query();
    // ....
}
```

Then you can call that by turning the query inside `GetAll` into a compatible lambda.  `ToListAsync<T>` returns a `Task<List<T>>` which can be used as `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` (because of how async methods are translated by the compiler).  That `T` is what's in `DefaultCollection`, which is `TEntity`, and the task object returned by `ExecuteCmd` is what's awaited in `GetAll`.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll(int skip = 0, int limit = 100)
{
    return await ExecuteCmd(
        () => DefaultCollection
            .Find(Filter.Empty)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Limit(limit)
            .ToListAsync()
        );
}
```

`skip` and `limit` are captured by the lambda, which is why the delegate takes no arguments.

You could pass the task object directly through like this:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll(int skip = 0, int limit = 100)
{
    return ExecuteCmd(
        () => DefaultCollection
            .Find(Filter.Empty)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Limit(limit)
            .ToListAsync()
        );
}
```

This can look cleaner because you don't need the `async` and `await` keywords.  The disadvantage is that you lose stack information in exceptions and it can be harder to track down where an exception is occurring.  I think most experts would advise against this but the decision is ultimately yours.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly :) Always, great to learn new things, have a great day.